# How to make MEMS IR Thermal Sensor - D6T-44-L06 work with Arduino?

Tags: sensors, arduino-yun, temperature-sensor

I am working on project that my team need to detect the presence of the people. At first, we tried with motion sensor but it wasn't the way that we want it to work. We want to detect presence of the people even they don't move.

We decide to go with Omron Thermal Sensor D6T-44-L06. However, there lacking of tutorial or simple code online that actually show how to connect that Omron thermal sensor with Arduino. How can I interface this with Arduino?

Answer (score 1):

Yes should be really easy to implement, as it work like almost all i2c sensor; this manual as also some code example, the chip address, and finally the registry address; that is all you need.
http://www.mouser.com/pdfdocs/D6T01_ThermalIRSensorWhitepaper.pdf